# App Engine PHP Wordpress Remote File Uploads

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

So I just installed Wordpress for Google App Engine PHP - and it seems like I cannot change the site's static files from the back-end of the deployed site (For example, I have no option to "Add Plugin" and I get a flash error if I try to upload an image from media center).  The SQL works fine - I can add text to pages ...but not images.

Is this intentional?  Am I supposed to add all my static files/plugins locally and then deploy them to App Engine?

Apologies if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Last time I checked, app engine was not supporting any filesystem writing functions for php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the [App Engine plugin.](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-app-engine/)

It has a section on configuring the Google Cloud Storage bucket to use for storing the uploads.

More info on running WordPress [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress).

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

Yes it is intentional. You are supposed to add all static files/plugins locally and then deploy them to App Engine?

**Explanation:**

On the [Quick Start Wordpress for App Engine doc](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/), the last paragraph states:

> Note: You'll want to keep that local copy of WordPress handy, because you'll need it to install custom themes and plugins. Because of the security sandbox, your live WordPress site can not write to the local files -- they're static. This means the auto-installation of themes and plugins in the WordPress dashboard will only work in the local WordPress that you run on your own machine. So, remember to do all your installing locally, then re-deploy your WordPress app.