# Error Message after uploading images to new Wordpress Appengine website

Tags: php, image, google-app-engine, wordpress

Is anyone experiencing problems uploading images to Wordpress sites on App Engine that are running today's plugin update?

I have just deployed a new Wordpress website and spent the day pulling my hair out trying to workout why I was getting a redirect loop error message, when I should have arrived at the /install.php screen.

After much stress I discovered that we need to add the following into wp-config.php now...

define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com/' );

See here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10553

But now my problem is that I'm unable to display any images?

After uploading on Wordpress I get this message: “xxxxx.png” has failed to upload due to an error
The uploaded file could not be moved to [my-bucket].

Yet when I look on my cloud console, the images are in my bucket???

But when I look in my media library on Wordpress, no images are present???

This happens whether or not the new tick box in the plugin enabled.

But it doesn't happen on a site I've had live for quite a while that is running the updated version of the plugin.

A solution or any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: is the cloud storage bucket correctly configured in the bucket? is this a brand new app you just created?

Comment: Tried creating a new bucket, checked permissions, etc, still no success. This is a new app, deployed for the first time yesterday.

Comment: Please check this answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104027/app-engine-php-wordpress-remote-file-uploads

Cheers